# Physical principles and their rigidity

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, quantum-gravity, theory-of-everything, unified-theories

In many of his talks and interviews, Nima Arkani-Hamed mentions how incredibly constrained are the laws of physics.

For example, in a recent interview he says:

> “[I]f we just took these general principles, just the general principles of relativity and quantum mechanics, and tried to figure out what  could  the world look like, just mathematically thinking from those important physical principles, following them to their logical conclusion, it turns out to be astonishingly constrained.”

I do understand his point quite clearly and actually have found manifestations of this rigidity plenty of times, but usually in a very informal/non-technical way. An example is an argument for the existence of antiparticles used by Feynman in his book “Elementary Particles ad the Laws of Physics.”

My question is the following: is there a book or article where these constraints (this **almost** inevitability) are discussed more quantitatively and in more detail?

Weinberg’s book DFT also considers the topic, but I was looking for something more mathematically robust.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The concept of "constrained" here appears to be more philosophical than scientific.   You could argue equally that Newton's Laws are rigid & constrained... until we reach situations where Special Relativity is significant.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Physics from Symmetry is a good book for you http://physicsfromsymmetry.com/